# ffmpeg -itsoffset option has no effect

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to fix audio sync problems. I looked in MPC-HC that audio should be delayed by 2750 milleseconds.

The following two commands

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset +2.750 -i MyFile.avi -vcodec copy -ss 00:28:32 -to 00:29:30 MyFile2.avi
ffmpeg -itsoffset -2.750 -i MyFile.avi -vcodec copy -ss 00:28:32 -to 00:29:30 MyFile2.avi
```

give exactly the same result (video and audio non synchronized and shifted equally).

I.e. `-itsoffset` option does not work.

Why?

Comment: the option `-itsoffset` applies to all streams of the following input file. So it delays both video and audio. See the above (duplicate) question.

Answer (score -1):

If your video codec is using B-Frames it could cause this. You might have to end up transcoding to something that uses all I-Frames, for example

```
-c:v huffyuv
-c:v ffv1
-c:v ffvhuff
```

Comment: I don't want to recode video. Why can't `ffmpeg` recode audio as it needed?